# Sharing a dynamically started worker among several consumers

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am building a worker class that connects to an external event stream using asyncio. It is a single stream, but several consumer may enable it. The goal is to only maintain the connection while one or more consumer requires it.

My requirements are as follow:

- The worker instance is created dynamically first time a consumer requires it.
- When other consumers then require it, they re-use the same worker instance.
- When the last consumer closes the stream, it cleans up its resources.

This sounds easy enough. However, the startup sequence is causing me issues, because it is itself asynchronous. Thus, assuming this interface:

```
class Stream:
    async def start(self, *, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
        pass
    async def stop(self):
        pass
```

I have the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1** - exception at startup

- Consumer 1 requests worker to start.
- Worker startup sequence begins
- Consumer 2 requests worker to start.
- Worker startup sequence raises an exception.
- *Both consumer should see the exception as the result of their call to start().*

**Scenario 2** - partial asynchronous cancellation

- Consumer 1 requests worker to start.
- Worker startup sequence begins
- Consumer 2 requests worker to start.
- Consumer 1 gets cancelled.
- Worker startup sequence completes.
- *Consumer 2 should see a successful start.*

**Scenario 3** - complete asynchronous cancellation

- Consumer 1 requests worker to start.
- Worker startup sequence begins
- Consumer 2 requests worker to start.
- Consumer 1 gets cancelled.
- Consumer 2 gets cancelled.
- *Worker startup sequence must be cancelled as a result.*

I struggle to cover all scenarios without getting any race condition and a spaghetti mess of either bare Future or Event objects.

---

Here is an attempt at writing `start()`. It relies on `_worker()` setting an `asyncio.Event` named `self._worker_ready` when it completes the startup sequence:

```
async def start(self, timeout=None):
    assert not self.closing
    if not self._task:
        self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._worker())

    # Wait until worker is ready, has failed, or timeout triggers
    try:
        self._waiting_start += 1
        wait_ready = asyncio.ensure_future(self._worker_ready.wait())

        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            [self._task, wait_ready],
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, timeout=timeout
        )
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        wait_ready.cancel()
        if self._waiting_start == 1:
            self.closing = True
            self._task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                await self._task    # let worker shutdown
        raise
    finally:
        self._waiting_start -= 1

    # worker failed to start - either throwing or timeout triggering
    if not self._worker_ready.is_set():
        self.closing = True
        self._task.cancel()
        wait_ready.cancel()

        try:
            await self._task        # let worker shutdown
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            raise FeedTimeoutError('stream failed to start within %ss' % timeout)
        else:
            assert False, 'worker must propagate the exception'
```

That *seems* to work, but it seems too complex, and is really hard to test: the worker has many `await` points, leading to combinatoric explosion if I am to try all possible cancellation points and execution orders.

I need a better way. I am thus wondering:

- **Are my requirements reasonable?**
- **Is there a common pattern to do this?**
- **Does my question raise some code smell?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements sound reasonable. I would try to simplify `start` by replacing `Event` with a future (in this case a task), using it to both wait for the startup to finish and to propagate exceptions that occur during its course, if any. Something like:

```
class Stream:
    async def start(self, *, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        if self._worker_startup_task is None:
            self._worker_startup_task = \
                loop.create_task(self._worker_startup())

        self._add_user()
        try:
            await asyncio.shield(asyncio.wait_for(
                self._worker_startup_task, timeout))
        except:
            self._rm_user()
            raise

    async def _worker_startup(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)      # ...
        self._worker_task = loop.create_task(self._worker())
```

In this code the worker startup is separated from the worker coroutine, and is also moved to a separate task. This separate task can be awaited and removes the need for a dedicated `Event`, but more importantly, it allows scenarios 1 and 2 to be handled by the same code. Even if someone cancels the first consumer, the worker startup task will not be canceled - the cancellation just means that there is one less consumer waiting for it.

Thus in case of consumer cancellation, `await self._worker_startup_task` will work just fine for other consumers, whereas in case of an actual exception in worker startup, all other waiters will see the same exception because the task will have completed.

Scenario 3 should work automatically because we always cancel the startup that can no longer be observed by a consumer, regardless of the reason. If the consumers are gone because the startup itself has failed, then `self._worker_startup_task` will have completed (with an exception) and its cancellation will be a no-op. If it is because all consumers have been themselves canceled while awaiting the startup, then `self._worker_startup_task.cancel()` will cancel the startup sequence, as required by scenario 3.

The rest of the code would look like this (untested):

```
    def __init__(self):
        self._users = 0
        self._worker_startup = None

    def _add_user(self):
        self._users += 1

    def _rm_user(self):
        self._users -= 1
        if self._users:
            return
        self._worker_startup_task.cancel()
        self._worker_startup_task = None
        if self._worker_task is not None:
            self._worker_task.cancel()
            self._worker_task = None

    async def stop(self):
        self._rm_user()

    async def _worker(self):
        # actual worker...
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hmmm, cancelled coroutines need to be awaited as well, and the `wait_for` should `asyncio.shield` the task, else cancellation will be propagated. But I like the splitting of add/rm user into separate methods.

Comment: @spectras I've now added the shield, but I'm not sure why cancelled coroutines should be awaited. What is the adverse effect of *not* awaiting them?

Comment: If stop is called as part of the shutdown process, not awaiting them can result in the loop closing before they are done. Also, if cancellation raises an exception, it will go unnoticed. In this specific example, the worker flushes some buffers and gracefully notifies the other end of willing termination upon cancellation.

Comment: I answered my own question using your help, encapsulating the result in a reusable class, then trimming it down until I am happy with it. Thanks for the ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

With my previous tests and integrating suggestions from @user4815162342 I came up with a re-usable solution:

```
st = SharedTask(test())
task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(st.wait())
task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(st.wait(timeout=15))
task3 = asyncio.ensure_future(st.wait())
```

This does the right thing: task2 cancels itself after 15s. Cancelling tasks has no effect on `test()` unless they all get cancelled. In that case, the last task to get cancelled will manually cancel `test()` and wait for cancellation handling to complete.

If passed a coroutine, it is only scheduled when first task starts waiting.

Lastly, awaiting the shared task after it has completed simply yields its result immediately (seems obvious, but initial version did not).

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress


class SharedTask:
    __slots__ = ('_clients', '_task')

    def __init__(self, task):
        if not (asyncio.isfuture(task) or asyncio.iscoroutine(task)):
            raise TypeError('task must be either a Future or a coroutine object')
        self._clients = 0
        self._task = task

    @property
    def started(self):
        return asyncio.isfuture(self._task)

    async def wait(self, *, timeout=None):
        self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._task)

        self._clients += 1
        try:
            return await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(self._task), timeout=timeout)
        except:
            self._clients -= 1
            if self._clients == 0 and not self._task.done():
                self._task.cancel()
                with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                    await self._task
            raise

    def cancel(self):
        if asyncio.iscoroutine(self._task):
            self._task.close()
        elif asyncio.isfuture(self._task):
            self._task.cancel()
```

---

The re-raising of task exception cancellation (mentioned in comments) is intentional. It allows this pattern:

```
async def my_task():
    try:
        await do_stuff()
    except asyncio.CancelledError as exc:
        await flush_some_stuff()     # might raise an exception
        raise exc
```

The clients can cancel the shared task and handle an exception that might arise as a result, it will work the same whether `my_task` is wrapped in a `SharedTask` or not.

Comment: `suppress(asyncio.CancelledError)` looks like it will make the consumer uncancellable while the originally cancelled task is cleaning up. (The cancellation occurring at that time will just be swallowed.)

Comment: @user4815162342 It is counter-intuitive, but it doesn't make it uncancellable. `suppress` does not prevent the exception from occurring an cancelling the task, it only prevents it from bubbling up.

Comment: I get that; the part that worries me is that if a `CancelledError` doesn't bubble up from that point, the cancelled task will have some other exception as the result. Maybe it's not a problem in practice, but to me it's not obvious that that won't interfere with the cancellation mechanism. If I suppressed `CancelledError`, I'd be careful to re-raise it after doing whatever it is I need to do to handle it.

Comment: This is by design: if [shared task cancellation as a result of the last client being cancelled] raises an exception, then that last client gets the exception *(the same it would have gotten if task was not wrapped in `SharedTask`)*. Should one want another behavior, use `suppress(Exception)` instead (and add some logging mechanism, one definitely does not want exceptions to go unnoticed).

Comment: I was referring to cancellation of the last client that happens to occur while awaiting the cleanup of the shared task. For this to occur, the shared task must have been cancelled or the `wait_for` has timed out. (The third possibility would be for `self._task` to have exited with an exception, in which case the task has already completed and its `cancel()` would be no-op.) So suppressing the `CancelledError` will either replace it with another `CancelledError` or with an `TimedoutError` at the `raise` below. The latter replacement might be a bit strange, but should probably not cause issues.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes. Well there is a test for `self._task.done()` that prevents the third possibility, but the other two remain. Alas, as one can only raise one exception, a choice had to be made. I guess YMMV as to which is most relevant. It is one of those times exceptions show their limitations as an error handling mechanism.

Comment: In general I _think_ you want to (re-)raise the last one - this is how `finally` raising an exception works, for example. (Python 3 introduced chaining of tracebacks precisely to support this usage.) But you're right that a choice has to be made and no choice is perfect.